# Replace substring surrounding main string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a lot of strings like the following:

```
\frac{l_{2}\,\mathrm{phi2dd}\,\sin\left(\varphi _{2}\right)}{2}
```

I want to replace the `\frac{***}{2}` to `\frac{1}{2} ***`

The desired string would then become:

```
\frac{1}{2} l_{2}\,\mathrm{phi2dd}\,\sin\left(\varphi _{2}\right)
```

I thought I could use a regular expression to do so, but I can't quite figure out how to extract the 'main string' from the substring.

---

**Update:** I simplified the problem a bit too much. The strings I have to replace actually contain multiple 'fracs', like so:

`I_{2}\,\mathrm{phi2dd}-\frac{l_{2}\,\mathrm{lm}_{4}\,\cos\left(\varphi _{2}\right)}{2}+\frac{l_{2}\,\mathrm{lm}_{3}\,\sin\left(\varphi _{2}\right)}{2}=0`

I don't know the number of occurances in the string, this is varying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match using `\\frac\{(.*?)\}\{2}` and substitute using `\\frac{1}{2} \1`

**Updated code:**

```
import re

regex = r"\\frac\{(.*?)\}\{2}"
test_str = "I_{2}\\,\\mathrm{phi2dd}-\\frac{l_{2}\\,\\mathrm{lm}_{4}\\,\\cos\\left(\\varphi _{2}\\right)}{2}+\\frac{l_{2}\\,\\mathrm{lm}_{3}\\,\\sin\\left(\\varphi _{2}\\right)}{2}=0"
subst = "\\\\frac{1}{2} \\1"

# 4th argument decides how many occurences to replace
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: @hungersoft I made a mistake in the problem statement, I have multiple occurances in one string. Using your solution only the outer occurance is replaced, how can I replace all the occurances?

Comment: The new regex has a '?' which makes the regex non-greedy and matches multiple occurences.